# Get process id of a running metro app

Tags: c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I want to get the process id of a running Metro app programatically via C++ code, from another process. I have the static information of that app like name, full name etc. What is the API to do that?
I can't use EnumProcess since the running Metro App is being run inside app container WWAHost.exe, so I can't know which of the running WWAHost.exe processes is actually running *my* Metro App.

In process explorer, I noticed that the Current directory of the WWAHost.exe process which is executing my Metro App is same as metro app install location. Could this be the differentiating factor between all the running app containers? If yes, what is the way to get current directory of another process?

To update, I have got some a solution regarding this on msdn forums. Here's the link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/c9665bf4-00e4-476c-badb-37126efd3f4b/

But, the solution uses an undocumented mechanism on Windows to get current directory of another process. I would like to use that solution only if there's no other way.

Answer (score 2):

You want to call [GetApplicationUserModelId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on each WWAHost process.

The sample application provided allows you to pass in a PID and get back the information about the app. For instance:

```
C:\src\GetAppInfo\Debug>GetAppInfo.exe 7400
Process 7400 (handle=00000044)
Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **GetForegroundWindow** to get current active window, after that use **GetWindowThreadProcessId** to get PID of current window, then valid if is a WindowsStore app with **IsImmersiveProcess**, then **GetPackageId** to get app package info, like package name, version...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetCurrentProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms683180.aspx) to get process id.

Comment: I missed the fact that i need process id of metro app from another process. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: There isn't a call to do that, as far as I know. So you probably stuck with the solution you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GetPackageId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetPackagePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then read info about app from AppxManifest.xml

Comment: but that info won't give any hint on which process is hosting that app especially for Javascript based apps