# Get path of a Metro (Modern UI) app on Windows 8/8.1

Tags: winapi, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

How do I get the path of the foreground metro app on Windows **8** and Windows **8.1** using WINAPI?

For example if the foreground app is 'Weather' then the app-specific path that I'm looking for is:

> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.BingWeather_2.0.0.310_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe

This information is shown in the Task Manager if you right-click properties on an app. However I want too retrieve it programmatically using WINAPI.

I tried using `GetForegroundWindow`, `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and `QueryFullProcessImageName` but this only returns the path of the WWAHost container process ("C:\Windows\System32\WWAHost.exe") instead of the app-specific path described above.

Windows 10 metro apps also run in a container however one of the child HWND's is owned by an app-specific process. By searching for this HWND I was able to get the app-specific path on Windows 10. However on Windows 8/8.1 there are only 3 HWNDs and they are all owned by the WWAHost container process so this trick didn't work.

Comment: *WinRT* and *Metro* (that should really be *Modern UI*) are distinct systems. A desktop app can use the Windows Runtime just as well. Please update the question title to make it less confusing.

Comment: Avoid asking an XY question, explain why knowing the path is important to you.

Comment: I stumbled across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824770/get-process-id-of-a-running-metro-app/32192620#32192620) answer to a related question. I haven't had a chance to test it yet but it looks like it will do what I want.